# Variable has private access javax.swing.AbstractButton

Tags: java, swing

I want to add a new variable to my button. To do that, I create a new class extending JButton and make a constructor in there. Am I doing something wrong? But it says: "action has private access javax.swing.AbstractButton"

```
public class MyButton extends JButton{
   MyButton(String name, int act){
   super(name);
   action = act;
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what it says. You are trying to access a private variable from the superclass. And that's not allowed for it's `private`. Perhaps there's a setter for action (i.e. `setAction`). Or perhaps there is a super constructor accepting both `name` and `action`.

Comment: You code doesn't do what you think it does, and I think that you may be confused as to what `action` represents for AbstractButtons. For one, it is not an int but rather of type Action. If I were you, I'd re-think what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I tried changing the variable`s name, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: You're asking an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it, because all we can say at this point is that "your answer lies in a different castle".

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a new variable to my button.

So where are you defining the new variable?

You need to use a variable name that is NOT used by any of the super classes. It just happens that "action" is the variable used to save the "Action" of the JButton.

The code should be something like:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton
{
    private in myNewVariableName

    MyButton(String name, int act)
    {
         super(name);
         myNewVariableName = act;
    }
}
```